# Indentifying the dimensions of vector spaces consisting of polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $P_n$ denote the set of polynomials of degree $n$ with coefficients in $\Bbb F$. 
Let $P^0_{n}$ denote the subspace of all $p \in P_n$ such that $p(0)=0$

For $k ≥ 0$, let $p_k(x)$ = $x^{k+1}− x^k$. Let $V_n$ = span($p_0,··· ,p_n$). Show that dim($V_n$) = dim($P_{n+1}^0$) but $V_n$ $\neq$ $P_{n+1}^0$. What is the dimension of $V_n$$\cap P_{n+1}^0$?

It seems intuitive to me that $(p_0, ...,p_n)$ are linearly independent, because each term is of different degree and so can't be written as a linear combination of the previous terms, but I'm not sure how to prove this. If they are linear independent, then the $dim(V_n)=n+1$.

Comment: Oh I should also mention that $P^0_{n+1}$ is the subspace of $p_n$ such that p(0)=0

Comment: Ive got that $p_0$ through $p_n$ are linear independent and so the dimension of $V_n$ is n+1

Comment: @MiltonFriedman: If you think you have already found out the dimension of $V_n$, you should edit your question and post it there. Also your explanation of the symbol $P^0_{n+1}$ should be included in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you have to figure out what $\dim(P^0_{n+1})$ is. (Hint: At first, you may verify that all the polynomials in this subspace are of the form $a_{n+1}x^{n+1}+...+a_1x$ where the $a_i$ are in $\mathbb{F}$.)

In order to show that $P^0_{n+1}$ is not equal to $V_n$, it suffices to show that there is one polynomial in $V_n$ which is not in $P^0_{n+1}$. (Hint: Consider the polynomial $p_0$.)

You can solve the last part of your problem (the part concerning the intersection $V_n \cap P_{n+1}^0$) if you investigate the subspace
$$\text{span}(p_1,...,p_n)$$
a bit closer.

$\textbf{Edit}$: I have just seen that you added more information to your question. So, here is a hint how to prove the linear independence of $p_0,...,p_n$: Assume
$$0=a_np_n+...+a_1p_1+a_0p_0$$
where $a_i \in \mathbb{F}$. This means
$$\begin{align}
0 &=a_n(x^{n+1}-x^n)+a_{n-1}(x^n-x^{n-1})+...+a_1(x^2-x)+a_0(x-1) \\
  &=a_nx^{n+1}-a_nx^n+a_{n-1}x^n-a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+...+a_1x^2-a_1x+a_0x-a_0 \\
  &=a_nx^{n+1}+(-a_n+a_{n-1})x^n+...+(-a_1+a_0)x-a_0 \\
\end{align}$$
Now, remember that a polynomial equals the $0$-polynomial iff all the coefficients are equal to $0$. Apply this to the last line of the above equation.

Comment: That's very helpful, thanks!

Comment: @MiltonFriedman: Note my recent edits. Maybe they help you.